# 500 error when using a "Redirect 301" rule in htaccess

Tags: htaccess, apache

I am trying to redirect an old URL

```
http://example.com/keyboard/keyboardchart.php?gam=7&sty=15&lay=1
```

to a new URL

```
http://example.com/keyboard/keyboard-chart.php?gam=7&sty=15&lay=1
```

using `.htaccess`.

Here is the contents of `example.com/keyboard/.htaccess`:

```
IndexIgnore *
Redirect 301 keyboardchart.php keyboard-chart.php
```

However, I get a "500 Internal Server Error" when navigating to the old URL.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Redirect 301 keyboardchart.php keyboard-chart.php
> ```

The 500 error is because the target URL is *relative*. That is not allowed with a mod_alias `Redirect`. The target URL must either be absolute (with a scheme and hostname) or must start with a slash (ie. root-relative).

But also, the source URL-path will not match either. You must specify a root-relative URL-path, starting with a slash.

Regardless of where the `.htaccess` file is located, the mod_alias `Redirect` directive is the same. Unlike mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) that has the concept of a "directory-prefix".

So, like VladShundalov suggests, you would need a directive of the form:

```
Redirect 301 /keyboard/keyboardchart.php /keyboard/keyboard-chart.php
```

Note that this matches *any* query string. The query string is automatically passed through to the target. You can't actually match the query string with a mod_alias `Redirect`.

If you need to match the specific query string then you must use mod_rewrite instead. For example, in the `example.com/keyboard/.htaccess` file you could write something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^gam=7&sty=15&lay=1$
RewriteRule ^keyboardchart\.php$ /keyboard/keyboard-chart.php [R=301,L]
```

Note that you don't state the subdirectory on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* in this case, however, you do still need a root-relative path on the *substitution* (unless you specify the path with a `RewriteBase` directive). The query string is passed through to the substitution automatically by default.

Comment: Fixed `RewriteRule` _substitution_ string. Added info about query string.

Answer (score -1):

Quick and dirty way - try, it should work.

```
Redirect 301 /keyboard/keyboardchart.php?gam=7&sty=15&lay=1 /keyboard/keyboard-chart.php?gam=7&sty=15&lay=1
```

If You have a lot of such URL then look forward using rewrite rules.

Comment: The `Redirect` directive matches against the URL-path only, not the query string. If you specify a query string then it will never match (as it tries to match it against the URL-path). Just remove the query string and it should work.